# Django data model policies

Tags: python, django, django-models

We have a Django-based website driven by a fairly involved data model, which has a growing number of Model types. Increasingly, the models have been gaining dependencies. While so far, we have been dealing with these interdependencies in an ad-hoc manner, we are now looking to formalize them declaratively.

The main type of dependency is of the following kind:
"If an object of type A is created, then also create an object of type B, and link it through foreign key a"

...but in general, the idea is to react to the creation and update of models by updating, creating or deleting other models. Are there any frameworks or mechanisms in Django that support this type of functionality?

Comment: I guess Django's built-in signals do not satisfy your needs somehow?

Comment: Yes, that or overriding save(), update() etc. in the model is an option. I'm open to everything, but was hoping there might be a declarative rule-based framework somewhere, which lets you say things like "Student(s) => StudentEnrollment(student=s)" If not, then that's what I'm going to develop.

Comment: I'd have thought signals or manager functions for create/delete which deal with child/relations might be the way forward